# Spring Boot Debug mode in Eclipse Photon not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging

I am launching a Spring boot application
I have set a breakpoint when Spring boot instance is running, Eclipse don't catch any breakpoint.

I setted the goal:

```
spring-boot:run
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse IDE.  spring-boot:debug Could not find goal 'debug' in plugin org.springframework.boot

Comment: sorry can you try this `mvnDebug spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 0):

Option A:
Go to the main class > right click > debug as java application

Option B:
Use the following command, and from eclipse set up remote debugging for your project on the port 5870

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5870"
```

Comment: I opened maven run configuration, in tab JRE in VM arguments and put -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5870.  But when I launch it I have in console "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5870" and Spring boot don't start

Comment: At this point, maven build is actually waiting for a debugger client to connect to your JVM on port 5870, so just do this> on project right click>  debug as> debug config> remote java app> (host: localhost, port 5870) > click debug.

Comment: Or since u are using eclipse, u could just right click on ur main class file, and choose debug as java application...

Comment: Option A not works. Spring boot now starts but it doesn't stop on breakpoint

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your main class, it could be that you placed your breakpoint in an unreachable code block, and make sure u are using the correct port

Comment: No I am sure, I am in the repository that retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

Try using debug perspective in Windows tab and show perspective debug